# subprocess.communicate on perf stat does not return expected stdout, stderr

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, perf

I was trying to run perf stat within Python using subprocess.
I noticed a behavior which I think is curious, this is the code:

```
import subprocess
cmd="perf stat -e cache-misses echo stdout"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()

print "OUT",out
print "ERR",err
```

And this is the output:

```
 Performance counter stats for 'echo stdout':

             1,759 cache-misses                                                

       0.000868593 seconds time elapsed

OUT stdout

ERR
```

The output of the command which is profiled by perf is correctly returned as stdout. The stats from perf should be returned on the stderr, instead they are printed on screen instead of saved in the err variable after the communicate.

I also tried to remove the `shell=True` but it does not change the result.

Why does this happen?

Comment: [What stream does perf use?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89594) seems relevant.

Comment: Try `perf stat -x, -e ...`. The -x flag produces machine-readable output. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat

Comment: My `perf --version` says `perf version 0.0.2.PERF` and it does what you'd expect: the `perf` output is captured in `err`.

Comment: @John Zwinck I am using perf version 3.2.63.

Comment: @Himal Thanks for the link, this does solve my problem but I am not sure what is happening there. perf output should be either on stderr or stdout otherwise I would not see it on the terminal. Why is it not captured by subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on Ubuntu 14.10 and it seems to work. The output will be in `stderr_output`:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = ['perf', 'stat', '-x,', '-e', 'cache-misses', 'echo', 'stdout']
    print 'cmd:', cmd
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_output, stderr_output = process.communicate()

    print "\nOutput:"
    print stdout_output,

    print '\nError:'
    print stderr_output
```

## Discussion

- I splitted the command into a list and it works, leave it as one string and it doesn't
- I did not have to use `shell=True`
- If you don't want the machine-readable output, remove the `-x,` option

Comment: Which version of perf are you using?

Comment: I'm at work at cannot check, but I installed that last night.